# Reference an index from array on creation (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible in PHP to reference an array index on creation of the array?

For example, I need to create a list that will only be used once, in this case to map a word to an index. I know this can be done in Perl, and I think Javascript but can't get it to work in PHP.

```
$fruit = 2;
$fruitName = ( array( "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Kiwi"))[$fruit];

echo $fruitName;
```

This should output **Banana**, is this possible or do I have to create the array first?

I realise that I'm just being lazy trying to shortcut it, and I also realise that this post is 7 lines so could have done this 7 times already in the time it took to ask lol

Comment: just remove the `()` this should be `$fruitName = array( "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Kiwi")[$fruit];`

Comment: Thanks RxV seems my PHP version is the issue. I think I did that cos in Perl you'd do @(list)[index], just tried it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to delete  `()` and then it should work (PHP > 5.4 , see: http://3v4l.org/YpThG)

```
$fruit = 2;
$fruitName = array( "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Kiwi")[$fruit];

echo $fruitName;
```

Output:

```
Banana
```

Also for more information about array dereferencing see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ah thanks! I'm running 5.3 so that's why. Current stable is 5.6, do you know if that's fully compatible? Don't want to break my app for the sake of a 1 liner.

Comment: @Dabrowski On 5.3 it doesn't work you would have to first assign it to a variable. If you have 5.6 then it's no problem!

Comment: Yep, I get that, I can upgrade to 5.6 no problem just wanted to check if it's fully backwards compatible but I can always switch it back. Thanks again.